# Section Break (Next Page) vs Section Page (Odd Page)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft

I am using MS Word on MacBook to write a book which is about 250 pages. My problem started when I applied 'Section Break (Odd Page) after every section to start a new chapter on the odd page. It created new blank pages after References & Notes which I cannot delete. I need guidance on how to remove/delete extra blank pages and how should I avoid adding new blank pages at the end of the document. Would Section Break (Next Page) solve the issue and in that case, I understand that I have to apply Section Break (Next Page) on the blank page.

Thanks.

Sajjad
janjuha@hotmail.com

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the odd-page section break is that it will always start the following section on an odd page. If that means a page needs to be skipped when printing, that is what it will do.

You want the section break at the end of a section, not after it. "After" implies that you already have a section break at the end.

If a section ends on an odd page and you do not want a blank even page before the next section, then yes, you would use a next page section break.

Here are links to two references. The first is to my page, the second to one on the MVP FAQ site.

- [Sections, Headers and Footers in Microsoft Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm)
- [Working With Sections](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Formatting/WorkWithSections.htm) by Dave Rado, MVP